# Limit of call requests

Tags: java, android, mobile

I am new to Android and Mobile developement. I want to send off a high number* of call requests between 2 numbers. The calls should be dispatched and immediately canceled.

*) min. 10 times a second, max. 100 times a second

Is there a limit of calls I can start in a time period with Android?

1. Are there any other limitations using Android / Java?
2. Will providers probably block such a number of call requests?
3. Will the receiver reliably be noticed of the exact number of calls?

Edit: I am trying to figure out, how to communicate with only call requests and at no cost. No harassing or cheating.

Comment: How about you first finish your harassment app and then let us know?

I seriously doubt any carrier will do 10 calls per second. Your main limitation will be getting your users to accept that your application will be abusing their calling capabilities ergo, potentially charging them insane amounts of money.

Other than that, you just need `CALL_PHONE` permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml` and thats it.

Comment: You should read a bit about what a call really is (network-wise). Initiating a call from your phone does not necessarily means it will reach the destination in a fixed time. There are so many elements in this equations that I will definitely not rely on a call rate as you desrcibe

Comment: I am not trying to harass, fool or cheat on anybody. I want to set up a communication app.

Comment: You might need `MONITOR_OUTGOING_CALLS` permission too. But to do a quick feasability test out your 'communication' app, take two phones or just tell two friends to call you repeteadly within 2 minutes. Check with them how many times they called (20+), check how many missed calls you have on your phone. Check the text-message most carriers send to notify you of your missed calls. Discuss.

Comment: Thanks giorashc I will read more about it, as I said I am totally new to mobile stuff.

Comment: no problem, my point in general is that it is not in your app control the time it takes for a call to reach your destination so take that into account

Comment: Also, when you make a call and not have credit, once 'picked up' by the carrier infomercial, code-wise you will have made a successful call. Have that in mind too. There is no way to determine if you're reaching who you're calling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initiate calls to phone numbers using intents.

```
String number = "123-456-777-2";
String uri = "tel:" + number.trim() ;
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
startActivity(intent);
```

Like i previously said, you need the CALL_PHONE permission.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Note that if you use `ACTION_DIAL` you will be presented with an option of dialing the phone yourself (it'll be predialed in) and then you do not need the CALL_PHONE permission.

Comment: Thanks I am not yet coding, but will use your code for a test call.

Comment: IMHO, you really should first start coding this and when you hit your head on many rocks along the way, refine your initial idea and ask again.

Also, `startActivity` should probably be `startActivityForResult` here...

No offense, but anyone trying to make 10 calls per second obviously never used a mobile phone, or heard of roamin- i mean tethering :D

Comment: Again thanks for your input. I did not explain in detail what my intention is, but I am trying to figure out how to communicate with the simplest options and at no cost.

Comment: So you're making a auto-telegraph out of a mobile phone? Or turning it into a morse-encoder? :D I could see an SMS being transmitable over a 'ciphered call frequency' but .... really? Why not just make something .... more useful and earn money for the phone bill? :)

Comment: So your application will also need to be able to intercept any ringing call, or just those that happen while the app is running? What happens if you get a real call from person X during the "morse-burst" from person A? What about concurrency? Or will that be delegated to disciplined usage from the user? :)

Comment: The idea basically only works if I can send off a defined number of calls in a short period. Thats why I am here and I am still only thinking about it. Of course, there is no possibility to catch "real" calls while transmitting.

Comment: There is no possiblity to discern your app's calls from real calls - which means Cindy can use your app in a legitimate way to jam Alice's communication to Bob. Just because the app can catch a call from a predefined number (to regenerate the sent message) doesn't mean the phone can (first caller - as determined by carrier - rings)

It doesn't really sound very useful in a scenario for which you're making it for IMO. But it might be feasible, and useful for cheap file transfers or some such, or a form of slow-but-crypted communication. Something you'd use to anonymously confirm something.

Comment: Why should that be a problem? Even if Cindy is disturbing, the phone registers the call attempts and the app figures out the numbers. But indeed, Im just at the beginning...

Comment: The phone doesn't register the call attempts, it's carrier does. Which then, in their standard timely manner, notifies you. My carrier notifies me of all my missed call via a multipart SMS. Like a list saying "this number called you this many times". What I'm getting at here is - you cannot safely rely on call ordering or time.

Comment: Ok I understand. This might be a problem. If you want, you could sum up your input and I will accept it as an answer.

Comment: The answer was up there all along, that's how you'd programmatically do it.

Comment: It was not about coding in any way. Haha. However your input did help.